# How do I get webpack-dev-server to serve files?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm going through the docs for webpack 4 and trying to get webpack-dev-server running from a very simple configuration.

I've installed webpack-dev-server and added minimal configuration for it in my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    watch : true,

    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        port: 9999
    }

}; //config ends
```

However, when I run webpack and then navigate to http://localhost:9999, nothing is being served. There is no server listening for connections.

Comment: The dev server cannot find an index.html file to serve in the contentBase (,/dist), is it there or outside?

Answer (score 1):

You should change `contentBase: './src'` to make webpack-dev-server understand what is the directory you used for develop.

The `output` param is used for build to production not for `webpack-dev-server`